# I want to get result of intersection of two Select statements based on two columns intersection

Tags: sql

How can i make single select statement that combine both Select statements on the basis of only common 'PO' and 'Style Number' column

[image: First select statement result]

[image: Second select statment result]

Comment: Use `intersect`

Comment: When i use Intersect between these two queries i get empty results

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when i use intersect between these two select statements, i get empty result
i just want to intersect based on specific two columns is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tableA A
join tableB B
on A.PO = B.PO and A.StyleNumber = B.StyleNumber
```

Comment: i want to intersect result of two Select statements, not tables

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from (
   -- your first select query goes here
) a
inner join (
   -- your second select query goes here
) b
on a.PO=b.PO and a.stylenumber = b.stylenumber
```

I guessed you want inner join.